# DataGridView DataSource can't be added to

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, bindinglist

This part of my code is responsible for adding new items to my BindingList<DevicePropertyTable> called DeviceStorage

```cs
public void StoreDevice(string deviceName)
        {
            var device = new DevicePropertyTable()
            {
                IEEE = deviceName,
                StateRegister = ""
            };

            DeviceStorage.Add(device);
        }
```

The problem is, the code hangs on the .Add, because the DGV's DataSource has been assigned as this list.

If I assign it after I filled it with some data it displays correctly, but then I can'd add new items yet again. The DGV seems to hold my List hostage.

How would I go about making the list accessible? Since this code is in a seperate class from the Form, I can't access the DGV directly to just set the DataSource to null.

Comment: Is that code executed on a secondary thread, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, it's called on a separate thread that handles incoming network messages

Comment: Then that's the issue. You can't do things that affect the UI on any thread other than the UI thread. If your list is bound to a control then modifying that list will affect the UI, so you can't do it. You need to marshal a call to the UI thread to modify the list. [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?544824-Accessing-Controls-from-Worker-Threads)'s one I prepared earlier.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to give it a thorough read and construct an answer to my own question just in case someone finds this :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user18387401 said in the comments above, this is a problem with accessing the UI thread from a different thread. I got around this by adding 2 methonds and 2 invokers to my From:

```cs
public void ReleaseTableDataBindInvoker()
{
    mapping_table.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(ReleaseTableDataBind));
}

public void ReleaseTableDataBind()
{
    mapping_table.DataSource = null;
}

public void BindTableDataInvoker()
{
    mapping_table.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(BindTableData));
}

public void BindTableData()
{
    mapping_table.DataSource = DeviceTableStorage.getInstance().DeviceStorage;
}
```

note: mapping_table is the name of my DGV

and then I passed a reference to the form when starting the seperate thread, to access these methods. Then I simply release the bind, add my data and re-bind the table.

```cs
public static void HandleIncomingMessages(Form1 mainFrom)
        {
           //some code here
             
            mainFrom.ReleaseTableDataBindInvoker();
            DeviceTableStorage.getInstance().StoreDevice(device_friendly_name);
            mainFrom.BindTableDataInvoker();
        }
```